# How to change props outsite of the React root component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I have a react chart component which will be rendered after initializing an javascript object, looks like this:

```
    function Chart(width, height) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      // Render the whole chart
      this.chartRef = React.render(<ChartApp width={this.width} height={this.height} /> , document.getElementById("chart"));
    }
```

Then in a html, I initial it:

```
<script>
        window.globalChart = new Chart(width, height);
</script>
```

At this point, the chart could be rendered correctly on the browser, but problem is I want to change the `width` and `height` externally by introducing an prototype for the `Chart` object

```
// The width setter
Chart.prototype.setWidth = (width) => {
    // want to apply this new width for the ChartApp component
};
```

Hence, i can use the width setter from `globalChart` by invoke `globalChart.setWidth(newWidth)`,

So then I want the `ChartApp` will receive new width, and re-render the chart accordingly

How can I tackle it? Really get lost when thinking of the pattern I should use to make it work, please advice me, could i use `this.chartRef` to do anything ?

Comment: You can use the ``useImperativeHandle`` react hook here

Comment: @Tracer69 great, let me try. Thank you